# Get Greatest date across multiple columns with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have three entities: Group, Activity, and Comment. Each entity is represented in the db as a table. A Group has many Activities, and an Activity has many comments. Each entity has a CreatedDate field. I need to query for all groups + the CreatedDate of the most recent entity created on that Group's object graph.

I've constructed a sql query that gives me what I need, but I'm not sure how to do this in entity framework. Specifically this line: `(SELECT MAX(X)
                FROM (VALUES (g.CreatedDate), (a.CreatedDate), (c.CreatedDate))` Thanks in advance for your help. Here's the full query:

```
WITH GroupWithLastActivityDate AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT  
        g.Id
        ,g.GroupName
        ,g.GroupDescription
        ,g.CreatedDate              
        ,g.ApartmentComplexId
        ,(SELECT MAX(X)
            FROM (VALUES (g.CreatedDate), (a.CreatedDate), (c.CreatedDate)) AS AllDates(X)) AS LastActivityDate
    FROM Groups g
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Activities a
        on g.Id = a.GroupId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Comments c
        on a.Id = c.ActivityId  
    WHERE g.IsActive = 1
)
SELECT 
    GroupId = g.Id
    ,g.GroupName
    ,g.GroupDescription             
    ,g.ApartmentComplexId
    ,NumberOfActivities = COUNT(DISTINCT a.Id)
    ,g.CreatedDate      
    ,LastActivityDate = Max(g.LastActivityDate)     
FROM GroupWithLastActivityDate g
INNER JOIN Activities a
    on g.Id = a.GroupId
WHERE a.IsActive = 1
GROUP BY  g.Id
        ,g.GroupName
        ,g.GroupDescription
        ,g.CreatedDate
        ,g.ApartmentComplexId
```

I should add that for now I've constructed a view with this query (plus some other stuff) which I'm querying with a SqlQuery.